# Cordova template missed in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-templates

I had Visual Studio 2015 beta and everything worked correctly. After installing CTP 6 over the existing version of VS, updated version of Visual Studio left Hybrid app template.

I looked for a way to install it separately and tried to update Visual Studio again (to be sure that Hybrid plugin is checked) - without success. Moreover, I checked online templates in "Extensions and Updates" there are no this template. I checked "Installed products" there isn't the Hybrid plugin.

Is it possible to install the Hybrid plugin separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this in the simple way. I installed Visual Studio 2015 RC. This update overrode oldest changes and everything now works OK.

Answer (score -2):

While creating the new project, before selecting the template, search for cordova online and u will find the add-on.

Comment: As I mentioned, I was looking in online templates.